# Calulcating the norm of the exponential of a bounded operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, exponentiation, semigroup-of-operators

Let $X$ be a Banach space. If $A \in L(X)$ we know that we can define $e^{At}$ via the exponential formula:
$$e^{At}=\sum_{k=0}\frac{(tA)^k}{k!}$$
Now take $A=-I$ where $I$ is the identity.
In the book by Engel Nagel p.74 they use the fact that
$$|e^{-It}|_{L(x)}\leq e^{-t}$$
Of course by using the triangular inequality in the series one obtains $|e^{-It}|\leq e^{t |I|}=e^t$ but this is much weaker of course.
How is the other inequality proved?

Comment: For any function $f$ analytic at $z=1$ we have $f(I)=f(1)I.$ Therefore $\|f(I)\|=|f(1)|.$ In particular we can apply that to $f(z)=e^{-tz}.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$e^{(-I)t}= \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}  \frac {(-t)^{k}} {k!} I=e^{-t} I$. So $\|e^{-It}\|=e^{-t}$ (It is an equality).